# jQuery Mobile listview style not applying

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am working on a little side project, that is basically just a glorified RSS Reader for Google. I have the functions pulling the data successfully, but styling the list isn't working for reasons unknown to me. I was hoping this post will help me figure out where I went wrong.

The code is here in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ySCsd/2/

Though, I should note the cross origin policy is preventing the code from executing properly. It might be easier to just copy/paste into Dreamweaver or similar if you're going to try and help me.

This is what it does for me in Dreamweaver:
[image: List]

I think it has to do with the refreshing of the listview:

```
    $(listItem).appendTo(listView);
});

$(listView).appendTo('#items');
});

$('#items ul').listview('');
```

but I just can't get it right!

Thanks for any help, in advance.

-James

Comment: Where is your stylesheet physically located ? maybe start trying to set an absolute path to it

Comment: Ahh, I copy/pasted from another project and neglected to realize that my path is incomplete! It's supposed to be linking from the online repositories. 

Will post back after changes are made.

Comment: Alright, so I updated my CSS reference: http://jsfiddle.net/8EGGZ/117/

Still having the same issue. Can anyone provide additional input?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a stylesheet somewhere :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http:/fiddle.jshell.net/ySCsd/2/show/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css
```

If not, you can try a 'physical' reflow by doing so :

```
$('#items ul').css('display','none').css('display','block');
```

Comment: Jon, I added a comment above in which I made a change and added the stylesheet. See:http://jsfiddle.net/8EGGZ/117/ as it's still giving me a hard time.

Thanks!

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: selectScience is not defined //I can't seem to see the list

Comment: :\ 

I dislike jsfiddle as it doesn't ever work for me. Are there any solutions that actually work?